# Django - Data query based on user permissions or user group name

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm new to Python and started a project where I have a list of Customers that are distributed across different Regions of the world. System users should only have access to users in their own region

I added custom permissions for the class Customer.

I'm trying to find a way to list all the Customers in one or more regions (for example: latam, emea, us, ...) based on Authentication group name or user permission. Is that possible??

views.py

```py
class CustomerListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Customer
    context_object_name = 'customers'
    template_name = 'customers/customer.html'
    login_url = '/'
    permission_required = 'customer.view_customer'
    permission_denied_message = 'User has no permission to perform this action.'
```

model.py

```py
class Region(models.Model):
    region_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.region_name


class Customer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("latam_view", "Can acceess LATAM data"),
            ("us_view", "Can acceess US data"),
            ("emea_view", "Can acceess EMEA data"),
        )
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    primary_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=24, null=False, blank=False)
    primary_contact_position = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
    primary_contact_department = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=False)
    primary_contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=17, null=False, blank=False)
    primary_contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    customer_region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    auth_group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.customer_name
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're just learning, I recommend simplifying this.

Model:

```
class Customer(model.Models):
    is_latam = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_us = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_emea = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    other_fields = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

View:

```
def view_customer(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html', {customers: Customer.objects.all()})
```

Template:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
    {% if customer.is_latam %}
    Latam Data here
    {% endif %}
    {% if customer.is_us %}
    US Data here
    {% endif %}
    {% if customer.is_emea %}
    Emea Data here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hopefully this helps steer you in the right direction!

Comment: Hi Sam, actually I'm creating an inventory system for my company that need to filter the data by user group.

I appreciate the answer, but I would need a way to filter through the user's permission or user group name.

Is there any documentation that shows such procedure?

Thank you